# How to create a global configuration file for puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, puppeteer

I want to create a configuration file for puppeteer so that it takes all the settings from it. To avoid writing settings for each test, in the each test file. How can I do that?
. Now I am write these settings in `beforeAll` block for each tets.

For example, codecept JS has such a file. But I don't want to use this library - https://codecept.io/helpers/Puppeteer

I want something like this `"puppeteer.config.js" { headless: false, networkidle2 }` etc

I tried to make such a file. But I couldn't do it. puppeteer does not see these settings

my babelrc

```
{
  "presets":  [
    "@babel/preset-env"
  ]
}
```

my jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    preset: 'jest-puppeteer-preset',
};
```

my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.6.0",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "jest-puppeteer-preset": "^4.3.0",
    "puppeteer": "^1.20.0"
  }
}
```

my test

```
let page;
let browser;
const width = 1920;
const height = 1080;


beforeAll(async () => {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        args: [`--window-size=${width},${height}`]
    });
    page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({ width, height });
});

describe("Contact form", () => {
    test("first tests", async () => {
        await page.goto("https://uchebnik-stable.opk.su", { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
        await page.keyboard.press("Enter");
    }, 16000);
});
```

Comment: There is no config file for puppeteer for the launch options. You can instead write a helper function that calls the `puppeteer.launch` function with your options or you just read your file to pass it to the `puppeter.launch` call.